# Link in textview is not enabled in iPhone 4s landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am displaying some text in a UITextView, there is a mail id in the given text, So I enabled detect links property. This is working fine is both orientations in iPhone 3GS, but the link is not detecting in iPhone 4s landscape mode. Can any one help me.

Thanks in advance